# QCamera seems broken

Tags: android, c++, qt, camera

In order to use my phone camera (on a Nexus 5) I use this code :

```
camera = new QCamera;
camera->setViewfinder(ui->viewFinder);
ui->viewFinder->show();

ui->stackedWidget->setGeometry(0,0, 1000, 1700);
ui->viewFinder->setGeometry(0, 0, 1000, 1700);

camera->start(); // to start the viewfinder
qDebug() << camera->error() << camera->errorString();
qDebug() << camera->state() << camera->status();
```

coming from the [Qt doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/cameraoverview.html) but it doesn't do anything. I've added the correct includes in the header file and the `QT += multimedia multimediawidgets` in the .pro file.

The output is :

```
QCamera::NoError ""
QCamera::UnloadedState QCamera::UnloadedStatus
```

Which is kind of weird because if the `start()` function fails it should throw an error :

> void QCamera::start() [slot] Starts the camera.
>
> State is changed to QCamera::ActiveState if camera is started
>   successfully, otherwise error() signal is emitted.
>
> While the camera state is changed to QCamera::ActiveState, starting
>   the camera service can be asynchronous with the actual status reported
>   with QCamera::status property.

## EDIT

```
QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, cameras) {
qDebug() << cameraInfo.deviceName();
}
```

Outputs :

> "back"
>
> "front"

So QT detects the devices.

## EDIT 2

Here's some log which seems to contain a few errors but as it's my first android app, I not totally aware of what's going on :

```
D/dalvikvm(21060): GC_CONCURRENT freed 172K, 2% free 17025K/17228K, paused 5ms+1ms, total 22ms
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x42cb2588, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x42cb2588, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Network.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Network.so 0x42cb2588
I/Qt      (21060): Network start
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Multimedia.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Multimedia.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Multimedia.so 0x42cb2588, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x42cb2588, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so 0x42cb2588, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so 0x42cb2588, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Positioning.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Positioning.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/lib/libQt5Positioning.so 0x42cb2588, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so 0x42cb2588
I/Qt      (21060): qt start
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/qt-reserved-files/plugins/mediaservice/libqtmedia_android.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/qt-reserved-files/plugins/mediaservice/libqtmedia_android.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/qt-reserved-files/plugins/position/libqtposition_android.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.HUD/qt-reserved-files/plugins/position/libqtposition_android.so 0x42cb2588
I/QtPositioning(21060): Positioning start
D/dalvikvm(21060): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.HUD-1/libHUD.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.HUD-1/libHUD.so 0x42cb2588
D/dalvikvm(21060): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.HUD-1/libHUD.so 0x42cb2588, skipping init
I/Adreno-EGL(21060): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
D/OpenGLRenderer(21060): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is contained here;

[https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38233?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38233?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Basically - it isn't working.

I can confirm the camera never moves into mode 8 under 5.3 branch of QT.
5.2.1 allows images to be captured, but the viewfinder does not work.

I'm not sure what is going on, or why they would've stopped supporting this code.